# npm install failed on Mac OS

Tags: npm, installation

Could someone help me check what caused this problem?
I want to generate NFT profile pictures using HashLips/Generative-art-node.

OS: Mac OS
NodeJs: v16.14.0
npm: 8.3.1
Editer: VS code

here is the log:

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
1 info using npm@8.3.1
2 info using node@v16.14.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/zanke/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 6ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 5ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
23 verbose logfile /Users/zanke/.npm/_logs/2022-03-03T08_09_10_540Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 15ms
28 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
29 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
30 timing idealTree:init Completed in 20ms
31 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
32 silly idealTree buildDeps
33 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 0ms
34 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 1ms
35 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
36 timing idealTree Completed in 21ms
37 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 25ms
38 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 1ms
39 silly reify moves {}
40 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
41 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 4ms
42 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
43 silly audit bulk request {
43 silly audit   '@mapbox/node-pre-gyp': [ '1.0.5' ],
43 silly audit   abbrev: [ '1.1.1' ],
43 silly audit   'agent-base': [ '6.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   'ansi-regex': [ '2.1.1' ],
43 silly audit   aproba: [ '1.2.0' ],
43 silly audit   'are-we-there-yet': [ '1.1.5' ],
43 silly audit   'balanced-match': [ '1.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   'brace-expansion': [ '1.1.11' ],
43 silly audit   canvas: [ '2.8.0' ],
43 silly audit   chownr: [ '2.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'code-point-at': [ '1.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   'concat-map': [ '0.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'console-control-strings': [ '1.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   'core-util-is': [ '1.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   debug: [ '4.3.2' ],
43 silly audit   'decompress-response': [ '4.2.1' ],
43 silly audit   delegates: [ '1.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'detect-libc': [ '1.0.3' ],
43 silly audit   'fs-minipass': [ '2.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   'fs.realpath': [ '1.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   gauge: [ '2.7.4' ],
43 silly audit   glob: [ '7.1.7' ],
43 silly audit   'has-unicode': [ '2.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'https-proxy-agent': [ '5.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   inflight: [ '1.0.6' ],
43 silly audit   inherits: [ '2.0.4' ],
43 silly audit   'is-fullwidth-code-point': [ '1.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   isarray: [ '1.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'lru-cache': [ '6.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'make-dir': [ '3.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   semver: [ '6.3.0', '7.3.5' ],
43 silly audit   'mimic-response': [ '2.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   minimatch: [ '3.0.4' ],
43 silly audit   minipass: [ '3.1.3' ],
43 silly audit   minizlib: [ '2.1.2' ],
43 silly audit   mkdirp: [ '1.0.4' ],
43 silly audit   ms: [ '2.1.2' ],
43 silly audit   nan: [ '2.15.0' ],
43 silly audit   'node-fetch': [ '2.6.1' ],
43 silly audit   nopt: [ '5.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   npmlog: [ '4.1.2' ],
43 silly audit   'number-is-nan': [ '1.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'object-assign': [ '4.1.1' ],
43 silly audit   once: [ '1.4.0' ],
43 silly audit   'path-is-absolute': [ '1.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'process-nextick-args': [ '2.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'readable-stream': [ '2.3.7' ],
43 silly audit   rimraf: [ '3.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   'safe-buffer': [ '5.1.2' ],
43 silly audit   'set-blocking': [ '2.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'signal-exit': [ '3.0.3' ],
43 silly audit   'simple-concat': [ '1.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'simple-get': [ '3.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   string_decoder: [ '1.1.1' ],
43 silly audit   'string-width': [ '1.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   'strip-ansi': [ '3.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   tar: [ '6.1.11' ],
43 silly audit   'util-deprecate': [ '1.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   'wide-align': [ '1.1.3' ],
43 silly audit   wrappy: [ '1.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   yallist: [ '4.0.0' ]
43 silly audit }
44 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wrappy Completed in 68ms
45 timing reifyNode:node_modules/string-width Completed in 69ms
46 timing reifyNode:node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 69ms
47 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align Completed in 69ms
48 timing reifyNode:node_modules/simple-get Completed in 70ms
49 timing reifyNode:node_modules/path-is-absolute Completed in 69ms
50 timing reifyNode:node_modules/process-nextick-args Completed in 69ms
51 timing reifyNode:node_modules/number-is-nan Completed in 69ms
52 timing reifyNode:node_modules/object-assign Completed in 69ms
53 timing reifyNode:node_modules/once Completed in 69ms
54 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ms Completed in 69ms
55 timing reifyNode:node_modules/inflight Completed in 70ms
56 timing reifyNode:node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 70ms
57 timing reifyNode:node_modules/has-unicode Completed in 70ms
58 timing reifyNode:node_modules/chownr Completed in 70ms
59 timing reifyNode:node_modules/code-point-at Completed in 70ms
60 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 70ms
61 timing reifyNode:node_modules/abbrev Completed in 70ms
62 timing reifyNode:node_modules/brace-expansion Completed in 71ms
63 timing reifyNode:node_modules/aproba Completed in 71ms
64 timing reifyNode:node_modules/set-blocking Completed in 72ms
65 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minipass Completed in 71ms
66 timing reifyNode:node_modules/mimic-response Completed in 71ms
67 timing reifyNode:node_modules/make-dir Completed in 71ms
68 timing reifyNode:node_modules/lru-cache Completed in 71ms
69 timing reifyNode:node_modules/inherits Completed in 71ms
70 timing reifyNode:node_modules/decompress-response Completed in 71ms
71 timing reifyNode:node_modules/console-control-strings Completed in 72ms
72 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-minipass Completed in 72ms
73 timing reifyNode:node_modules/signal-exit Completed in 73ms
74 timing reifyNode:node_modules/yallist Completed in 73ms
75 timing reifyNode:node_modules/util-deprecate Completed in 73ms
76 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs.realpath Completed in 72ms
77 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minimatch Completed in 72ms
78 timing reifyNode:node_modules/balanced-match Completed in 73ms
79 timing reifyNode:node_modules/safe-buffer Completed in 74ms
80 timing reifyNode:node_modules/string_decoder Completed in 74ms
81 timing reifyNode:node_modules/npmlog Completed in 73ms
82 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minizlib Completed in 73ms
83 timing reifyNode:node_modules/simple-concat Completed in 75ms
84 timing reifyNode:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 75ms
85 timing reifyNode:node_modules/isarray Completed in 74ms
86 timing reifyNode:node_modules/core-util-is Completed in 75ms
87 timing reifyNode:node_modules/concat-map Completed in 75ms
88 timing reifyNode:node_modules/debug Completed in 75ms
89 timing reifyNode:node_modules/delegates Completed in 75ms
90 timing reifyNode:node_modules/nopt Completed in 75ms
91 timing reifyNode:node_modules/detect-libc Completed in 76ms
92 timing reifyNode:node_modules/are-we-there-yet Completed in 76ms
93 timing reifyNode:node_modules/glob Completed in 77ms
94 timing reifyNode:node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 78ms
95 timing reifyNode:node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver Completed in 78ms
96 timing reifyNode:node_modules/https-proxy-agent Completed in 79ms
97 timing reifyNode:node_modules/agent-base Completed in 79ms
98 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-fetch Completed in 81ms
99 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge Completed in 81ms
100 timing reifyNode:node_modules/readable-stream Completed in 86ms
101 timing reifyNode:node_modules/tar Completed in 88ms
102 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp Completed in 89ms
103 timing reifyNode:node_modules/semver Completed in 91ms
104 timing reifyNode:node_modules/nan Completed in 93ms
105 timing reifyNode:node_modules/canvas Completed in 93ms
106 timing reify:unpack Completed in 94ms
107 timing reify:unretire Completed in 1ms
108 timing build:queue Completed in 2ms
109 timing build:link:node_modules/detect-libc Completed in 2ms
110 timing build:link:node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 2ms
111 timing build:link:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 2ms
112 timing build:link:node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp Completed in 2ms
113 timing build:link:node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver Completed in 1ms
114 timing build:link:node_modules/semver Completed in 1ms
115 timing build:link:node_modules/nopt Completed in 2ms
116 timing build:link Completed in 2ms
117 info run canvas@2.8.0 install node_modules/canvas node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
118 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 1150ms
119 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 1152ms
120 silly audit report {
120 silly audit report   'simple-get': [
120 silly audit report     {
120 silly audit report       id: 1006931,
120 silly audit report       url: 'https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wpg7-2c88-r8xv',
120 silly audit report       title: 'Exposure of Sensitive Information in simple-get',
120 silly audit report       severity: 'high',
120 silly audit report       vulnerable_versions: '>=3.0.0 <3.1.1'
120 silly audit report     }
120 silly audit report   ],
120 silly audit report   'node-fetch': [
120 silly audit report     {
120 silly audit report       id: 1006899,
120 silly audit report       url: 'https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g',
120 silly audit report       title: 'node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor',
120 silly audit report       severity: 'high',
120 silly audit report       vulnerable_versions: '<2.6.7'
120 silly audit report     }
120 silly audit report   ]
120 silly audit report }
121 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:simple-get:CfOTKibitQPLcCOtoiNMjQWiTsIdTxBIEgmmzGfYOefAN673X9eKBphpxXZ188QSF3cfnwnc9CgLPJQnthm+aQ== Completed in 4ms
122 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:node-fetch:uaZ3UpetgMoaSFDS6DtQK9+5KXhDQHg9nxPjdRKLpQbF/XdpCvGUNsQpackRFbF2Kj8o/EnjD2og3Lza4bG1eQ== Completed in 4ms
123 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-get 284ms (cache revalidated)
124 timing metavuln:packument:simple-get Completed in 285ms
125 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:simple-get:1006931 Completed in 1ms
126 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:simple-get:1006931 Completed in 287ms
127 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-fetch 787ms (cache revalidated)
128 timing metavuln:packument:node-fetch Completed in 790ms
129 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:node-fetch:1006899 Completed in 2ms
130 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:node-fetch:1006899 Completed in 792ms
131 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:canvas:vIE4EEvmO28bpJrSEZwrAnyUCVYUn67z6kGn1rgpe+XSS4hs9OWmLS8LIHS7T390ppW7ifiDpy5AT8wwhjPyaA== Completed in 3ms
132 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas 260ms (cache revalidated)
133 timing metavuln:packument:canvas Completed in 262ms
134 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:canvas:CfOTKibitQPLcCOtoiNMjQWiTsIdTxBIEgmmzGfYOefAN673X9eKBphpxXZ188QSF3cfnwnc9CgLPJQnthm+aQ== Completed in 1ms
135 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:canvas:CfOTKibitQPLcCOtoiNMjQWiTsIdTxBIEgmmzGfYOefAN673X9eKBphpxXZ188QSF3cfnwnc9CgLPJQnthm+aQ== Completed in 264ms
136 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:@mapbox/node-pre-gyp:1muVjrCRJhBXDmS0XOk1EPdyjTIUf23qc8/X38z+vDX2yzWRczdDWmpuftGoGK7RxGgzW2yiu6vGNDbuP+2Ixw== Completed in 3ms
137 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@mapbox%2fnode-pre-gyp 280ms (cache revalidated)
138 timing metavuln:packument:@mapbox/node-pre-gyp Completed in 282ms
139 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:@mapbox/node-pre-gyp:uaZ3UpetgMoaSFDS6DtQK9+5KXhDQHg9nxPjdRKLpQbF/XdpCvGUNsQpackRFbF2Kj8o/EnjD2og3Lza4bG1eQ== Completed in 0ms
140 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:@mapbox/node-pre-gyp:uaZ3UpetgMoaSFDS6DtQK9+5KXhDQHg9nxPjdRKLpQbF/XdpCvGUNsQpackRFbF2Kj8o/EnjD2og3Lza4bG1eQ== Completed in 282ms
141 timing auditReport:init Completed in 1341ms
142 timing reify:audit Completed in 2493ms
143 info run canvas@2.8.0 install { code: 1, signal: null }
144 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 34ms
145 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
146 timing command:install Completed in 15715ms
147 verbose stack Error: command failed
147 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
147 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
147 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
147 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
148 verbose pkgid canvas@2.8.0
149 verbose cwd /Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main
150 verbose Darwin 21.2.0
151 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
152 verbose node v16.14.0
153 verbose npm  v8.3.1
154 error code 1
155 error path /Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas
156 error command failed
157 error command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
158 error Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
159 error node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
159 error node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.5
159 error node-pre-gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
159 error node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
159 error node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
159 error node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@16.14.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
159 error node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
159 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
159 error gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
159 error gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
159 error gyp info ok 
159 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
159 error gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
159 error gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
159 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
159 error gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
159 error gyp info spawn args [
159 error gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
159 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
159 error gyp info spawn args   'make',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/zanke/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/zanke/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/zanke/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
159 error gyp info spawn args   'build',
159 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
159 error gyp info spawn args ]
159 error /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
159 error gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
159 error gyp ERR! configure error 
159 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
159 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:259:16)
159 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
159 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
159 error gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
159 error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
159 error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas
159 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
159 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
159 error gyp ERR! not ok 
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/zanke/Downloads/generative-art-node-main/node_modules/canvas
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.5
159 error node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
160 verbose exit 1
161 timing npm Completed in 15809ms
162 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1646294950633
163 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1646294950764
164 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1646294950764
165 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1646294950764
166 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1646294950768
167 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/canvas 1646294950768
168 verbose code 1
169 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
169 error     /Users/zanke/.npm/_logs/2022-03-03T08_09_10_540Z-debug-0.log
```

Not sure what's going wrong. Any given advices will be super appreciated.
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing "node-sass" to "sass" in package.json. Of course, set correct version.

node-sass was declared deprecated on Oct 2020.